# Parsley new violation customized by me doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twig, parsley.js

I'm using parsley.js to validate my form.
I want to check if an element exists in my database with ajax.
SO i did this :

```
   {{ form_widget(form.companyname, {'attr': {'class': 'md-input', 'required':'', 'data-parsley-company':'3'}}) }}

    <script>
        $('#sbcplatformbundle_fournisseur_companyname').on('change', function () {
            $comanyname = $('#sbcplatformbundle_fournisseur_companyname').val();
            var url = '{{ path('fournisseur_bycompanyname', {'companyname': 'companyName'}) }}';
            url = url.replace('companyName', $comanyname);
            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                success: function (json) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
                    if (json.success == true) {
                        // declancher une exeption
                        window.Parsley.addValidator('company', {
                            validate: function (value) {
                                return value;
                            }
                        }).addMessage('en', 'This company name already exists');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

this doesn't work for the first change. and in the second change i found this warning message at consile :

> main_Mask_parsley.min_1.js:16 Validator "company" is already defined.

how i must do it?

Comment: this code is adding the validator for 'company' on every ajax request - should only add it once (and before the request happens)

Answer (score 1):

Your code shows a couple of confusions:

- You should not trigger the validation yourself but tell Parsley how to do it.
- Register custom validators once at init time.
- No need to do the ajax call yourself, use the `remote` validator.

Good luck